# jquery dropdown keep option selected not working with dropdown js

Tags: jquery, selected, dropdown

I am using a jquery function to design a select option, but I am having an issue with the keep option selected.

Can it be changed via external jquery hook or by changing code in the JavaScript file?

I tried to modify the code with no luck.

Here is my fiddle

Comment: Fiddle:->  https://jsfiddle.net/r6r25ak2/2/

Comment: Can you please elaborate your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated fiddle. Please check it.

`My code is here`https://jsfiddle.net/r6r25ak2/4/